# How to find the values being swapped in two different arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, swap

I am suppose to swap an array with the odds in one array and the evens in another while keeping track of the count and the values being swapped.

```
{2, 3, 6}
{1, 4, 7}

will become

{1, 3, 7}
{2, 4, 6}
```

With 2 swaps, and the values being swapped are
`1` &`2`, `6` & `7`.

```
int main() {
    int a1[3] = { 2, 3, 6 };
    int a2[3] = { 1, 4, 7 };
    int i;
    int swapcount = 0;
    int swapvalue;

    std::cout << "Before swap:\n" << endl;
    std::cout << "Array 1:\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << " " << a1[i] << endl;

    }
    std::cout << "Array 2:\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << " " << a2[i] << endl;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (a1[i] % 2 != 1) {
            swapcount++;
            int temp = a1[i];
            a1[i] = a2[i];
            a2[i] = temp;
            swapvalue = i;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "After swap:\n" << endl;
    std::cout << "Array 1:\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << " " << a1[i] << endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Array 2:\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << " " << a2[i] << endl;

    }

    std::cout << "swap count: " << swapcount << endl;
    std::cout << "swap value: " << swapvalue << endl;
}
```

So far, I have gotten the `swap` and `counter` to work but I cannot seem to figure out:

How to find and store the individual values of the elements that are swapped? (I can get only one value to show.)

Can I get any hints on how to all grab the values? I am not allowed to use any additional libraries except for the input and output streams. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an auxiliary array swapbool, set boolean = 1 if a swap is done.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a1[3] = { 2, 3, 6 };
    int a2[3] = { 1, 4, 7 };
    int swapbool[3] = {0,0,0};
    int i;
    int swapcount = 0;
    int swapvalue;

    std::cout << "Before swap:\n" << endl;
    std::cout << "Array 1:\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << " " << a1[i] << endl;

    }
    std::cout << "Array 2:\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << " " << a2[i] << endl;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (a1[i] % 2 != 1) {
            swapcount++;
            int temp = a1[i];
            a1[i] = a2[i];
            a2[i] = temp;
           // swapvalue = i;
            swapbool[i]=1;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "After swap:\n" << endl;
    std::cout << "Array 1:\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << " " << a1[i] << endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Array 2:\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << " " << a2[i] << endl;

    }

    std::cout << "swap count: " << swapcount << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if(swapbool[i] == 1)
        {
            std::cout << "swapvalue1-> " << a2[i] << endl;
            std::cout << "swapvalue2-> " << a1[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    //std::cout << "swap value: " << swapvalue << endl;
}
```

Comment: Welcome :). I am not sure, whether this is space efficient, as we are creating an entirely new array to do the work, there could be a better space efficient way to do, for example, Create an integer- we have 4 bytes - 32 bits , so we can handle an array of size of 32. If we can just set the bit in this integer corresponding to the index of the array, then we have saved lot of space.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways of doing it. The simplest solution is to store them in `std::vector` of `std::pair`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> swapvalues;
```

And then inserting:

```
swapvalues.emplace_back(val1, val2);
```

By the way, in your code you store index, not values. If you want to store indices, use only `std::vector` of integers.

Comment: Hi, we are not allowed to use any other libraries. I appreciate the tips and will keep that in mind. Sorry, I am pretty new to this.

Answer (score 0):

> How to find the individual values of the elements that are swapped?

When you swap the elements store their indexes:

```
 int swappedValuesIndex[];

 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (a1[i] % 2 != 1) {
        // store swapped values' index  
        swappedValuesIndex[swapcount] = i;

        swapcount++;

        int temp = a1[i];
        a1[i] = a2[i];
        a2[i] = temp;
        swapvalue = i;
    }
 } 

 // print swapped values
 for (int i = 0; i < swapcount; i++){
     cout <<"a1["<< swappedValuesIndex[i] <<"]"<< a1[swappedValuesIndex[i]] <<'\n';
     cout <<"a2["<< swappedValuesIndex[i] <<"]"<< a2[swappedValuesIndex[i]] <<'\n';
 }
```

Comment: I thought similar to this, but I guess tracking was required. So one alternative was to store in a vector. Another alternative is to store in an array itself, taking same space as original arrays, i shall post code.

Comment: do you want to store them or just want to see which are the values?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I would like to store the values and retrieve them later after the swap is finished.

Comment: Hi, I am posting an answer below, please check.